# How can I change these iframe properties into CSS?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe as follow:

```
<iframe src="https://xyz" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I tried changing its styling into CSS like this:

```
iframe {
  width: 600;
  height: 450;
  frameborder: 0;
  border: none;
  allowfullscreen: 0;   
}
```

However, it doesn't come out right.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: There's no `frameborder` (but `border` covers that) or `allowfullscreen` in CSS.

Comment: Hey, for what you want to achieve, it would be ideal if you went ahead and removed the 'inline styling' from the iframe itself within the html. 

Secondly, you've defined a value for your width and height without using pixels. 

Thirdly, you're using 'frameborder' and 'allowfullscree' which are specific to iframes, and therefore not supported by traditional stylesheets. Hope this helps.

Comment: @BenjaminTreadwell, thank you for the insight.  I didn't know about these unsupported properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can assign Id to Iframe and make the necessary changes in CSS. allowscreen and frameborder is not CSS property.

HTML

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://xyz" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

CSS

```
#iframe {
 width: 600px;
 height: 450px;
 border: none;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This article explains it pretty well https://www.lifewire.com/iframes-and-css-3468669

Basically, you can style the IFrame itself, or you can (sometimes) style the page inside the IFrame.  You seem to want to do the former.

You should be able to style the IFrame similar to how you do it with HTML, but the article explains it pretty well, and I would suggest reading it.

In the article, this is a code snippet that is referenced, and from my quick testing it seems that you can do **some** styling in CSS, but HTML changes are ideal.

```
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 14px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 14px #000;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 14px #000;
-moz-transform:rotate(20deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);
-o-transform:rotate(20deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(20deg);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=.2);
}
```

I hope that helps/clears things up!

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply CSS to HTML that is loaded in an Iframe unless you have control over the page loaded in the iframe due to cross-domain resource restrictions.
This meaning that Iframes that originate from your server or a locally hosted webpage may have CSS styling applied to them. If you are getting the Iframe from a server which is not your own, ex. YouTube Iframe, you will not be able to apply your styling.